# 2 Related Poems by Rimbaud and Verlaine

Tags: poetry, identification-request, french-language, paul-verlaine, arthur-rimbaud

I'm looking for two poems by Rimbaud and Verlaine. They escape to Belgium together, went to a town party, and both wrote a poem about the event. Verlaine was really straightforward, and classical. Rimbaud was more powerful and deep, you can almost see the fireworks.

I use those poems to compare their work as a reference. But for some reason I cannot find them again.

Comment: Do you recall anything else about these poems? If you do, it might help us find them.

Comment: The Rimbaud poem is almost certainly [Fête d'hiver](http://www.unjourunpoeme.fr/poeme/fete-dhiver) but I'm unaware of a corresponding Verlaine poem. It has to be from *Romances Sans Paroles*, but none of the Brussels poems therein seems likely.